# Array index printing wrong value

Tags: java

I've the below Java code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cook {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[] = { 3, 1, 5, 2, 4 };
        getMaxValue(num);
    }

    public static void getMaxValue(int[] num) {
        int maxValue = num[0];
        int getMaxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (num[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = num[i];
            }
        }
        getMaxIndex = Arrays.asList(num).indexOf(maxValue);
        System.out.println(getMaxIndex + " and " +maxValue);
    }   
}
```

In the above code I'm trying to retrieve the maximum value in the array and also its index, but here the output that I'm getting is

```
-1 and 5
```

The max value is returned fine, but not sure of what's wrong with the index. This should actually print `2`, but it is printing `-1`, please let me know where am i going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thankd

Comment: Do you really need Arrays...indexOf in this code snippet?

Comment: If you took the time to do a little debugging, and inspected what every single one of the whole of 2 (!) functions that you use does, you would know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should update the max index in the loop :

```
    int maxValue = num[0];
    int getMaxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = num[i];
            getMaxIndex = i;
        }
    }
```

The reason `Arrays.asList(num).indexOf(maxValue);` returns `-1` is that an array of primitives is converted by `Arrays.asList` to a `List` of a single element (the array itself), and that `List` doesn't contain `maxValue` (it only contains the original array).

Answer (score 6):

Need to update index while iterating, `getMaxIndex = i;`

```
public static void getMaxValue(int[] num) {
        int maxValue = num[0];
        int getMaxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (num[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = num[i];
                getMaxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getMaxIndex + " and " + maxValue);
    }
```

**output**

```
2 and 5
```

Below is something @Eran is referring to.

It is converted to `List` of `size 1`, containing a single element (the array itself).

As per Javadoc,**[indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)**

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

So it searches for `maxValue` `inside List` and `not inside array stored in 0th index of List`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Everyone gives good hints, but no one explains in detail why it doesn't work.

`Arrays.asList()` is defined with the signature `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)` which takes a variable number of objects or just an array of objects.

However, `int` is a primitive type and not an object type. So `Arrays.asList(num)` is not interpreted as "take this array", but as "take this object as one object". The result is thus a `List<int[]>`, where the given number (of course) can't be found.

So it is better to keep the index while searching for the maximum, as the other answers already suggest.

Answer (score 1):

above answers are correct but you can also do

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num[] = { 3, 1, 5, 2, 4 };
        getMaxValue(num);
    }

    public static void getMaxValue(Integer[] num) {
        int maxValue = Arrays.asList(num).get(0);
        int getMaxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(num).get(i) > maxValue) {
                maxValue = Arrays.asList(num).get(i);
            }
        }
        getMaxIndex = Arrays.asList(num).indexOf(maxValue);
        System.out.println(getMaxIndex + " and " +maxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all these transformations with `Arrays.asList` ? If you're using an `Integer[]`, just do: `List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(num); int max = Collections.max(l); int indexMax = l.indexOf(max);`. 3 lines...